# Vagrant up and "warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_FILENAME"

Tags: ruby, vagrant, berkshelf

When I try to to do Vagrant up I get this error msg:

```
Failed to load the "berkshelf" plugin. View logs for more details.

Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

Failed to load the "vagrant-berkshelf" plugin. The output from loading
the plugin is shown below. View the logs for complete details.

stdout: 

stderr: /Users/user/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/berkshelf-2.0.18/lib/berkshelf.rb:25: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_FILENAME
/Users/user/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/berkshelf-2.0.18/lib/berkshelf/cookbook_generator.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant LICENSES
```

Berksfile is normally installed and everything worked fine till today, anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: er ma gerd, berks!  (more information is probably required to answer this question...)

Comment: @Okuma.Scott what informations do you need?

Comment: berkshelf configuration, for example...

Comment: Those stderr lines are just warnings. Run vagrant with `--debug` to hopefully get more information about the real issue.